# Android GoogleVR toolkit slow rotation

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope, google-vr

I'm developing application that uses GoogleVR Toolkit sensors to keep object on screen always in horizontal position. I works on Samsung Galaxy S3 but not on Samsung A5. On A5 I only get slow movement that barely correspond to what I'm trying to archive.


I suspect that this behaviour is caused because of the missing gyroscope in A5. How can I overcome this, or somehow guess the actual orientation of the device around all axes?

Comment: Did you try to compare movement with a compass sensor too?

Answer (score 0):

Rotation was really slow because of that missing sensor. I managed to get rotation info by myself from magnetometer. It was a bit shaky so I always make an average value from past 3-5 values to reduce the shakiness. More values you take into that average the more latency you add to that move.